# How to Integrate Custom Shipping method in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, soap-api-v2, webapi

I need to integrate Aramex Shipping method in magento 2, I have php sample code form Aramex.

```
    <?php
        $params = array(
            'ClientInfo'            => array(
                                        'AccountCountryCode'    => 'JO',
                                        'AccountEntity'         => 'AMM',
                                        'AccountNumber'         => '00000',
                                        'AccountPin'            => '000000',
                                        'UserName'              => 'user@company.com',
                                        'Password'              => '000000000',
                                        'Version'               => 'v1.0'
                                    ),

            'Transaction'           => array(
                                        'Reference1'            => '001' 
                                    ),

            'OriginAddress'         => array(
                                        'City'                  => 'Amman',
                                        'CountryCode'               => 'JO'
                                    ),

            'DestinationAddress'    => array(
                                        'City'                  => 'Dubai',
                                        'CountryCode'           => 'AE'
                                    ),
            'ShipmentDetails'       => array(
                                        'PaymentType'            => 'P',
                                        'ProductGroup'           => 'EXP',
                                        'ProductType'            => 'PPX',
                                        'ActualWeight'           => array('Value' => 5, 'Unit' => 'KG'),
                                        'ChargeableWeight'       => array('Value' => 5, 'Unit' => 'KG'),
                                        'NumberOfPieces'         => 5
                                    )
        );

        $soapClient = new SoapClient('http://url/to/wsdl.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
        $results = $soapClient->CalculateRate($params); 

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($results);
        die();
    ?>
```

I have all details, expect Soap Client Url, How to create wsdl file and What is the format of this Url in magento 2.

```
  $soapClient = new SoapClient('http://url/to/wsdl.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
```

Suggest me, How To Call Custom Api via magento 2.

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-aramex-shipping/

Comment: Thanks @magentotwo  I know that,  But I need to know how can I do that, not extenstions

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below URL, for magento2, which is provide module from Aramex.

https://marketplace.magento.com/aramex-shipping.html